# Magento shipping-zip-form missing

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, shipping, forms

I am currently receiving a strange bug on my cart site.

The form `shipping-zip-form` is gone missing on the page, althoug the default/base phtml for this is used (`magento/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart/shipping.phtml`)

The code contains:

```
<div class="shipping">
<h2><?php echo $this->__('Estimate Shipping and Tax') ?></h2>
<div class="shipping-form">
   <form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/cart/estimatePost') ?>" method="post" id="shipping-zip-form">
        <p><?php echo $this->__('Enter your destination to get a shipping estimate.') ?></p>
```

When i look in the cart i only receive:

```
<div class="shipping">
<h2>Geschätzte Versandkosten und Steuern</h2>
<div class="shipping-form">

        <p>Geben Sie Ihren Standort an, um die geschätzten Versandkosten/dauer zu ermitteln.</p>
        <ul class="form-list">
```

I tested a little bit arround with an override in my own theme and when i put the following line above the form:

```
<div id="testdiv"><form id="testform"></form></div>
```

It will then look like this:

```
<div class="shipping">
<h2><?php echo $this->__('Estimate Shipping and Tax') ?></h2>
<div class="shipping-form">
    <div id="testdiv"><form id="testform"></form></div>
    <form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/cart/estimatePost') ?>" method="post" id="shipping-zip-form">
        <p><?php echo $this->__('Enter your destination to get a shipping estimate.') ?></p>
```

And the frontend cart shows:

```
<div class="shipping-form">
    <div id="testdiv"></div>
    <form action="http://dev.suppastore.com/checkout/cart/estimatePost/" method="post" id="shipping-zip-form">
        <p>Geben Sie Ihren Standort an, um die geschätzten Versandkosten/dauer zu ermitteln.</p>
```

Notice: my testform is now missing instead of the shipping-zip-form.

The only thing i can currently think about is that an module is removing the form before the site is rendered.
Is there any way to figure out which module rewrites it?
Or is this probably a strange bug? When i activate the rwd theme it is not happening.

Comment: Have you tried disabling all the modules your installation uses and enabling them incrementally to find out whether a third party module is responsible? You can also give [mpmd](https://github.com/AOEpeople/mpmd) a try to see whether there are any unsettling core modifications which might cause this behavior.